# Returning subset of data in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table similar to

[image: |Name | Value | |-----| ------| |Cat1_subcat1 | 10| |Cat1_subcat2 | 5 | |Cat2_subcat2 | 10| |Cat1_subcat1 | 5 | |....|.....|]

I want to return only columns that contain 'Cat1'. Additionally, I want to only return rows where the Value of any Cat1_subcat1 is greater than 5. Any other subcategory associated with Cat1 has no restrictions.

So my query would look something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Name LIKE 'cat1%'
AND IF (Name = 'Cat1_subcat1', Value > 5) -- this line doesn't work, just an example of what I'm looking for
```

I feel like I can get around this by creating CTE's (or something similar) and using UNION but I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `if()`, just boolean logic:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Name LIKE 'cat1%' AND
      (Value > 5 OR Name <> 'Cat1_subcat1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Without entering into much detail about what's the better approach; you might achieve what you want using a combination of conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE (Name LIKE 'Cat1%' AND Name <> 'Cat1_subcat1')
OR (Name = 'Cat1_subcat1' AND Value > 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Others stated, an if might not be needed.
Your Idea with a CTE would work and you wouldn't need a UNION because you can chain CTEs. A UNION would result in a bigger resultset than you might want.

Let's take your Table(in my example I named it Testtable) for example

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Cat1_subcat1 | 10 |
| Cat1_subcat2 | 5 |
| Cat2_subcat2 | 5 |
| Cat1_subcat1 | 5 |
| Cat2_subcat2 | 10 |

A SELECT CTE with Union like this

```
WITH Test1 AS(
SELECT * FROM Testtable
    where Name like 'Cat%'
),
Test2 AS (
SELECT * FROM Testtable
    where Name = 'Cat1_subcat1' AND Value > 5
)
SELECT * FROM Test1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Test2
```

will result in

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Cat1_subcat1 | 5 |
| Cat1_subcat1 | 10 |
| Cat1_subcat2 | 5 |
| Cat2_subcat2 | 5 |
| Cat2_subcat2 | 10 |

I assume you are looking for something more like this

```
WITH Test3 AS(
SELECT * FROM Testtable
    where Name like 'Cat%'
),
Test4 AS (
SELECT * FROM Test3
    where Name = 'Cat1_subcat1' AND Value > 5
)
SELECT * FROM Test4
```

which will result in

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Cat1_subcat1 | 10 |

The same result can be achieved if you use the where statement with clever ANDs or ORs

```
SELECT * FROM Testtable
where Name like 'Cat%' AND (Name = 'Cat1_subcat1' AND Value > 5)
```

Try to play around with the ANDs and ORs to fit your needs